# Sobrecarga del operador < no funciona para 'priority_queue'

Tags: c++, estructuras-de-datos

El objetivo es crear una cola de prioridad de pares de enteros ( `pair<int,int>` ) que ordene de menor a mayor mirando el segundo elemento del par ( `second()` )

INPUT:

```
<5,8>
<2,4>
<3,9>
```

Estado de la cola de prioridad deseada después de insertar los elementos:

```
top -> <2,4> , <5,8> , <3,9>
```

Estado real de la cola al ejecutar el código:

```
top -> <5,8> , <3,9> , <2,4>
```

Como se puede observar, el criterio que sigue la cola para ordenar no tiene en cuenta el segundo elemento. Mas bien ordena como hacen por defecto las colas de prioridad.

**Por que no tiene en cuenta la sobrecarga del operador '<' ? Como podría solucionarlo?**

Código:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;


bool operator<(pair<int, int> const& c1, pair<int, int> const& c2) {
    if (c1.second < c2.second) return true;
    else if (c2.second < c1.second) return false;
    else return c1.first < c2.first;
}

int main() {
    int n, a, b;

    cin >> n;
    priority_queue<pair<int, int>> pq;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cin >> a >> b;
        pq.push({ a,b });
    }

    
    cout << pq.top().first << pq.top().second << endl;
    pq.pop();
    cout << pq.top().first << pq.top().second << endl;
    pq.pop();
    cout << pq.top().first << pq.top().second << endl;
    pq.pop();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si observamos cómo se define la [`std::priority_queue`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue):

> #### std::priority_queue
>
> ```
> template<
>     class T,
>     class Container = std::vector<T>,
>     class Compare = std::less<typename Container::value_type>
> > class priority_queue;
> ```

Vemos que el comparador usado por defecto es [`std::less`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less). En otras palabras: no está usando un operador definido externamente si no que usa un comparador interno. Para que use un comparador personalizado se lo debes pasar:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

// Alias del tipo de dato almacenado, por comodidad.
using pair_i = pair<int, int>;
// Función de comparación.
bool compare(const pair_i &c1, const pair_i &c2) {
    if (c1.second < c2.second) return true;
    else if (c2.second < c1.second) return false;
    else return c1.first < c2.first;
}

int main() {
    // Alias de la queue, por comodidad
    using pq_pair_i = priority_queue<pair_i, vector<pair_i>, decltype(compare)*>;
    //   Tipo de dato almacenado --> ^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    //                     Contenedor subyacente____/                /
    //                                    Función de comparación____/

    pq_pair_i pq(compare);

    pq.push({5,8});
    pq.push({2,4});
    pq.push({3,9});
    
    cout << pq.top().first << pq.top().second << endl;
    pq.pop();
    cout << pq.top().first << pq.top().second << endl;
    pq.pop();
    cout << pq.top().first << pq.top().second << endl;
    pq.pop();

    return 0;
}
```

Por cierto, comprueba tu función de comparación pues [ordena a la inversa de como describes](https://tio.run/##xZHraoQwEIV/m6cYKBQtqVTbQovWV5E0jtuAJjGXwrLss9t4q3ZfoP6Q8TvHMefItX7kHZOncbwTkne@QSiFss4g6yuys8GjxyP4Ru6UqQjxVsgTSNaj1YwjWNcUG9VMmFrAxzyUQjoK4VYF/VOpDrjqNTMYcyWt28z3PKNwQ/IELiQSLcQ8Sy0GtYESeL7OCRh03khwxmNBIuwswuzOD@7s1t2y4NvsKwuuVpjw7Xn9PBbkSkg4NvRMyHg6CYnWeEO9JzRCGeHO9dxUuXAKS03rY0WhQd65s54yz9mTh6mNaN@kh19pEVLt7Vd8eaVv10B2kNOXv@CZvk8AwkUirnzIUIZ1qVM6TrZUB7I1UwLKpls3TUrxz6@TaP0ZT6H6cfwB).